# Stuck with neice's homework!! Ostensibly a bearings question, but I need more to solve

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

My neice asked me for help with her national 5 homework. (National 5 is a new qualification in Scotland roughly equivalent to the old standard grade, so I would have thought quite easy). I have made a crude MS paint of the problem and linked it below.
[image]
Basically, with the information given, you need to work out the length QR.

Now, I have solved it, but I had split the triangle into two right angle triangles, create simultaneous equations to work out the length of the perpendicular line I drew to make the triangles, and the lengths that PR is split into by this line, and then finally Pythagoras to work out the length QR.

I don't remember problems this difficult when doing my Standard Grade, so am I missing something bleeding obvious, or is it really this difficult?

(The way I did it isn't difficult per se, just much more so than I remember problems at this level being)

I am no maths wiz, just the best she has in her immediate circle of friends/family.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that we can use the cosine formula here.... We can probably find out all the three angles of the triangle. We can then use those angles and the known side to find the length of QR.
In fact, thinking about it further, we should be able to use the sine law as well, making it even easier. 
Hope that helps. Don't feel like solving it, sorry. Hopefully someone a bit less lazy will come along, take my hint, and solve the problem. Or even better, you understand my hint and solve the problem yourself :D

Comment: Find the angles at $P$ and $R$ and solve the triangle.

Answer (score 3):

First use the geometric information to get the inner angles of the triangle: At $P$ it is $85^\circ$, at $R$ it is $180-125-(360-340)=35^\circ$, so at $Q$ it must be $180-85-35=60^\circ$.Now use the sine law: $\sin(60)/30=\sin(85)/x$, so $x=30\cdot \sin(85)/\sin(60)$.

Comment: This strategy works except that you have mixed up the cosine law and the sine law.

Comment: @john  Thanks -fixed